# is there away to find out if an apk is installed and if so open app

Tags: java, android, methods, installation, apk

hi guys some of my previous questions have been marked down so please be nice.

what i want to know is if there is a bit of code i can use that tell the user of my app that an apk is installed. then to open it within my app.

i have a listview, inside the list view is an list of available apps for download. i have worked out how to find out if the apk is there install instead of download. but i cant seam to figure out the installed bit.

ive tried this

```
public static boolean isPackageInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (intent == null) {
    return false;
}
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
return list.size() > 0;
```

}

then using

```
ispackageinstalled();
```

but this asks for Context, and string
so i tried add this to constructor

```
Context shb;
private Static String Showbox = "com.tk.Showbox";
```

then tried

```
ispackageinstalled(shb,Showbox);
```

and the app just crashes lol im obviously writing something wrong. also i would like for the selection to turn red if it installed if possible. but getting the app to open would be a great help cheers guys

Comment: If it crashes, post the logcat please. It would also be handy if you post more complete snippets of your code.

Comment: i posted more of the code yesterday and got marked down for it. so i thought i would start with what method i was using and work from there. i will post the logcat once i home later thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an actual `Context` to the method. Your `Activity` subclass that is hosting the `ListView` is a `Context`. Pass the `Activity` into your `ispackageinstalled()` method.

Comment: something like this ?   isPackageInstalled(downloads.this,Showbox)

Comment: @MarkMinecrafterHarrop: If `downloads` is the name of your `Activity` class, and `this` is somewhere inside of the activity (e.g., in an inner class somewhere), then yes.

Comment: thanks going try it now will get back to you. thanks for the help @commonsWare

Comment: its not causing the error any more but it doesnt seam to do anything. i call the method as soon as the item is clicked followed by an if statement for if its not installed. it seams to jump the ispackage installed statment

Answer (score 0):

found this worked the way i wanted

```
 private boolean isCallable(Intent intent) {

    if (intent == null) {
        return false;
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;

}
```

then making an Intent with the package details like this

```
Intent AllcastOpen = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.koushikdutta.cast");
```

then an if statement

```
 if (isCallable(AllcastOpen) == true) {
  AllcastInstalled.equals(true);

  startActivity(AllcastOpen);
```

the allcastInstalled is a seperate method that changes the color of the selection if its installed/downloaded depending